# Remove All Images Starting With This ID From Posts

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

**I have about 300 Wordpress posts, and on each one of them there is a "tracking pixel" from a service I used in the past (they use IMG tags to do so).**

It looks like this :

`<img id="serviceTrack_3274570" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important;" src="https://example-domain/e/ir?source=example148522" alt="example" width="0" height="0" border="0" />`

(each tracking pixel has a diffeent `serviceTrack_ID`).

**I would like to delete all these img id's (delete the images) from all my posts. How can I do that?**

Thank you !

Comment: pull the post field data into client-side code, use a dom parser to find/delete the relevant html snippet, then stuff the modified snippet back into the db. doing this in mysql will be painful, since you're restricted to plain string operations.

Comment: Are they in order or random id's?

Comment: They are pretty random. serviceTrack_3274570 , serviceTrack_3274581, serviceTrack_3274599 etc..

Comment: Marc B, Unfortunately I don't know how to do so - my programming skills aren't great. Is there a simple way to do so ?

Comment: Probably going to want to iterate through using something like this.  `document.querySelector('[id^="serviceTrack-"]').id;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got the necessary permissions, you could dump the db:

```
mysqldump -u yourUserName -p yourDatabaseName wp_posts > posts.sql
```

then replace the string:

```
find /path/where/you/put/dump/posts.sql -type f -exec sed -i 's/<img id="serviceTrack_*" 
 style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important;" 
 src="https://example-domain/e/ir?source=example148522" alt="example" width="0" height="0" 
 border="0" />//g' {} \;
```

then reimport the table:

```
mysqlimport -u yourUserName -p yourDatabaseName wp_posts < posts.sql
```

Disclaimer:  I haven't tested the replace command on actual data.  I recommend you back up your data before you try anything, and test it to in a dummy install before you overwrite your live data.

Comment: Thank you for that, I will see what I can do.